# Does The Rings of Akhaten explain the Eleventh Doctor’s line in Day of the Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who, the-day-of-the-doctor, gallifrey

When John Hurt's Doctor asked Matt Smith and David Tennant's Doctors if they count the children in Gallifrey before the galaxy eater, Matt Smith's doctor said he forgot about it (and his age).

Do you guys and gals think that all of those memories were lost because of the parasite from the Rings of Akhaten? It would make sense, right? The epic speech makes total sense in the context of the Doctor choosing to end the Time War via galaxy eater.

Answer (score 6):

When the Eleventh Doctor claims he's forgotten the number of children on Gallifrey, he's clearly lying. He knows exactly how many people he killed when he set off The Moment, but it's such a tragic memory that he chooses to forget. Thinking about how many children died merely reminds him of his own failure to save them. That memory represents everything he's been trying to run away from since the beginning of the revived series and the Ninth Doctor.

In particular, he's talking to the incarnation of The Doctor that actually did the thing that killed all those children, but that Doctor hasn't done it yet. So he (the War Doctor) doesn't realize just how painful the memory will be for his future selves. That makes it even harder for the other Doctors to talk to him about it; every time they look at him they just remember what they did/he's going to do.

On a completely different note, he's most likely lying about forgetting his age, as well. He seems perfectly capable of rattling it off when he wants to sound scary or impressive. There's about even odds that he's lying about knowing his age or lying about forgetting it.

Comment: That is true and totally possible. Thank you!  Although, during the Rings of Akhaten speech he basically did a simplified synopsis of either (1) Matt Smith's whole entire season or (2) all of the new Doctor Who's arching plots. So what happened with those memories?

Comment: Also, what if he was not lying. The premise of the moment is the war Doctor sees the man who regrets and the man who forgets. Wouldn't the ring of Akhaten be the catalyst of the Matt Smith's era in the grander picture?

Comment: @AdamTenasaputra: rule 1: The Doctor lies.

Comment: @AdamTenasaputra: I don’t remember a lot of the episode, because I thought it sucked, but reading the Wikipedia synopsis, I don’t think there’s any indication that the Doctor *lost* his memories when “giving” them to the creature. He was trying to satisfy it by giving it all his memories from his entire existence. If he lost them, he wouldn’t remember *anything*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Isn't that the purpose of the creature? To take the memories of his victim because he feeds on them. If he did sacrificed his memories then he would be confused of them? The doctor does lie to protect his companions. But will he also lie to protect himself?

Comment: @AdamTenasaputra: do we see anyone in the episode losing memories to the creature, in the sense of not being able to remember them? If not, then it seems like that isn’t how the monster works.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: True, however we see the leaf disappearing, and towards the end the doctor gave Clara's ring back because the people say they owe her their life - noting the importance of that leaf and implying it will nnot come back.

Comment: @AdamTenasaputra: sure, the leaf disappeared — if I give you a leaf, I don’t have the leaf any more. But if I tell you a memory, you now “have” the memory, but I still have it too. (That doesn’t mean that the monster *doesn’t* destroy memories when it takes them, but because we don’t see it destroying memories, it seems likely that it doesn’t).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: He would consume them, though. Perhaps the parasite can take memories, we see something happened like that via Time Heist in the new series. The writers messing with memories. Could it be possible that the doctor's memories are consumed by parasite, and he tries to attempt to remember and he just couldn't.

Comment: @AdamTenasaputra: well not really, because I’m pretty sure that later on in *Day of the Doctor*, the Doctor (at least Tenant’s one) says that he does remember the number of children on Gallifrey, and that he spent quite a lot of time counting them. It kind of undercuts the emotional impact of that if Smith’s Doctor wiped that memory out using a memory worm.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: So true, but Matt Smith's Doctor is the one that forgets, whereas Tenant's doctor is the one who regrets. Is the ring of Akhaten a basis of the Day of the doctor?

Comment: @AdamTenasaputra - Take it to chat, please.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Take it to chat, please.